# Problem with updating the data after the first try

Tags: c#

Allow me to present my code before i explain the issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Inventory_System_Redesigned
{
    public partial class AssetsModule : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
        DBConnect dbcon = new DBConnect();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        decimal batch = 0;
        decimal quantity = 0;
        private int aid = 0;
        private int assetID = 0;
        public AssetsModule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string[] items = { "Appliances", "Furnitures", "Glasswares" };
            cbCat.DataSource = items;
            cbCat.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cn = new OleDbConnection(dbcon.myConnection());
            cn.Open();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Asset Inventory1]";
            dt.Clear(); // Clear the data table
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm); // Pass the command to the data adapter
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvAssets.DataSource = dt;
            cn.Close();
        }
        private void dgvrefresh()
        {
            cn.Open();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Asset Inventory1]";
            dt.Clear(); // Clear the data table
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm); // Pass the command to the data adapter
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvAssets.DataSource = dt;
            cn.Close();
        }
        private void dgvAssets_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvAssets.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvAssets.SelectedRows[0];
                string asName = selectedRow.Cells["Asset Name"].Value.ToString();
                string cat = selectedRow.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
                string subcat = selectedRow.Cells["Subcategory"].Value.ToString();
                string desc = selectedRow.Cells["Asset Description"].Value.ToString();
                decimal batch = Convert.ToDecimal(selectedRow.Cells["Batch"].Value);
                decimal quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(selectedRow.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                DateTime pdate = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells["Date Purchased"].Value);
                DateTime we = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells["Warranty Expiration"].Value);
                aid = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["AssetID"].Value);
                tbAName.Text = asName;
                cbCat.SelectedItem = cat;
                cbSubCat.SelectedItem = subcat;
                rtbDesc.Text = desc;
                tbBatch.Text = batch.ToString();
                tbQuantity.Text = quantity.ToString();
                dtDP.Value = pdate;
                dtWE.Value = we;
            }
        }

        private void cbCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the selected category
            string selectedCategory = cbCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            // Add the appropriate sub-categories based on the selected category
            if (selectedCategory == "Appliances")
            {
                string[] subCategories = { "Electronics", "Computer", "Computer Parts" };
                cbSubCat.DataSource = subCategories;
            }
            else if (selectedCategory == "Furnitures")
            {
                string[] subCategories = { "Chairs", "Tables" };
                cbSubCat.DataSource = subCategories;
            }
            else if (selectedCategory == "Glasswares")
            {
                string[] subCategories = { "Utensils", "Vases" };
                cbSubCat.DataSource = subCategories;
            }
            cbSubCat.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            // Add more else-if statements as needed for additional categories

            // Select the first item in the sub-category combo box
            cbSubCat.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal batch;
            decimal quantity;
            if (!decimal.TryParse(tbBatch.Text, out batch))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid batch value");
                return;
            }
            if (!decimal.TryParse(tbQuantity.Text, out quantity))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid quantity value");
                return;
            }
            cn.Open();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Asset Inventory1] ([Asset Name], Category, Subcategory, [Asset Description], Batch, Quantity, [Date Purchased], [Warranty Expiration]) VALUES (@AssetName, @Category, @Subcategory, @AssetDescription, @Batch, @Quantity, @DatePurchased, @WarrantyExpiration)";
            cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbAName.Text;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Category", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Subcategory", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbSubCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetDescription", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rtbDesc.Text;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Batch", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = batch;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = quantity;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@DatePurchased", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtDP.Value;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@WarrantyExpiration", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtWE.Value;
            foreach (OleDbParameter param in cm.Parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", param.ParameterName, param.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(cm.CommandText);
            try
            {
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error inserting record: " + ex.Message);
            }
            dgvrefresh();
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal batch, quantity;
            if (!decimal.TryParse(tbBatch.Text, out batch))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid batch value");
                return;
            }
            if (!decimal.TryParse(tbQuantity.Text, out quantity))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid quantity value");
                return;
            }
            cn.Open();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.CommandText = "UPDATE [Asset Inventory1] SET [Asset Name] = @AssetName, Category = @Category, Subcategory = @Subcategory, [Asset Description] = @AssetDescription, Batch = @Batch, Quantity = @Quantity, [Date Purchased] = @DatePurchased, [Warranty Expiration] = @WarrantyExpiration WHERE AssetID = @AssetID";
            cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbAName.Text;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Category", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Subcategory", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cbSubCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetDescription", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = rtbDesc.Text;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Batch", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = batch;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = quantity;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@DatePurchased", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtDP.Value;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@WarrantyExpiration", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtWE.Value;
            cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = this.aid;
            foreach (OleDbParameter param in cm.Parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", param.ParameterName, param.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(cm.CommandText);
            Console.WriteLine(aid);
            try
            {
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error updating record: " + ex.Message);
            }
            dgvrefresh();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvAssets.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvAssets.SelectedRows[0];
                aid = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells["AssetID"].Value);

                cn.Open();
                cm.Connection = cn;
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Asset Inventory1] WHERE AssetID = @AssetID";
                cm.Parameters.Add("@AssetID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = this.aid;
                try
                {
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully");
                    cn.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error deleting record: " + ex.Message);
                }
                dgvrefresh();
            }
        }
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbAssetID.Text = String.Empty;
            tbAName.Text = String.Empty;
            cbCat.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cbSubCat.SelectedIndex = 0;
            rtbDesc.Text = String.Empty;
            tbBatch.Text = String.Empty;
            tbQuantity.Text = String.Empty;
            dtDP.Value = DateTime.Now;
            dtWE.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                cn.Open();
                cm.Connection = cn;
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Asset Inventory1] WHERE [Asset Name] LIKE '%" + tbSearch.Text + "%'";
                dt.Clear();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm);
                da.Fill(dt);
                dgvAssets.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvrefresh();
        }
    }
}
```

and if you want to see the DBConnect, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Inventory_System_Redesigned
{
    internal class DBConnect
    {
        private string con;
        public string myConnection()
        {
            con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\******\source\repos\Inventory System Redesigned\Inventory System Redesigned\ASIS_DATABASE.accdb""";
            return con;
        }
    }
}
```

I added ****** to the name for safety purposes
Ok now lets proceed with the issue.
What i want for the code to do is when this form is launched (initialized by the main form)
I want to perform CRUD actions. Inserting data works, deleting data works, searching, refreshing, etc... But when it comes to updating i have an issue that i cannot resolve.
The data just doesn't want to update after the first try. The first update operation for this data works and the second try doesn't. I have to keep relaunching the form just to update data in the database. I cannot do any massive changes anymore as i have to present a working code tomorrow.

I have tried making some adjustments to the code (as explained in the edit part), adding error handling methods like try catch blocks, as well as writing the processes in the Console but to no avail. I just can't find the error in the code and it has been frustrating me. I was expecting for this form to allow me to update everytime i select a row and not to repeatedly restart the form to update a single row of data.

Edit: I made certain changes like declaring aid again to 0 to see if the issue is the primary key not being accurate. By declaring aid to 0 after the cm.ExecuteNonQuery, i thought it would allow for another id to be declared into the data when a row selection is made to make sure that the aid changes to match the AssetID. I tried adjusting the command text to make sure that the arrangements as well as the column names match the sqlcommand. Again to no avail. I tried to print the values being inserted in the console, and the value of the initial and the aid change before the cm.ExecuteNonQuery to see if the ID is a mismatch, there was no mismatch and it printed the record updated succesfully message box but again, it did not update the data.

Comment: What is the structure of `[Asset Inventory1]` (primary/unique index,. etc.)? Is there error on second UPDATE?

Comment: You have made many tries and failed, but you didn't attempt to tell us the details. Do you expect someone to avoid all these tries and directly point out the error?

Comment: the AssetID is set as the primary key for the table with the autonumber data type. The Asset Name, Category, Subcategory, and Asset Description are set as Short Text data type and does not have a unique index. The Batch and Quantity are set as numbers with no unique index data type while the Date Purchased and Warranty Expiration are date/time data types and does not have a unique index as well. There is no catch exception in the second update as it proceeds with the MessageBox saying it was updated successfully but it did not update in the dgv and access

Comment: I apologize if i failed to tell the details, i edited my text to add the additional details of the changes i made

Comment: Let me explain it more clearly. You saw "Record Updated Successfully" dialog, so that the query was executed successfully. You saw nothing changed, there are 3 possibilities: 1. The where clause didn't hit, 2. The values you updated were equal to the original values. 3. It changed a little but you didn't notice. You are the only person who knows what were in the database and what the input values were.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info, ill double check my code if the where clause didn't actually hit. But the question is, why did the first one proceeded with the update while the other only showed the dialogue but did not update? As per the Console.WriteLine i used to verify changes, they are indeed both different values but they have the same primary key values.

Comment: MS access and c# connection is a pain, you can use old EF versions, there is an adapter. It's not the best, it can't do decimal update, or if your table has any type of float.